# How to Search Galaxy S-Finder with an Intent in Android?

Tags: android, galaxy

I want to search the Galaxy S-Finder app from an intent from an app. I know the package name. "com.samsung.android.app.galaxyfinder"

I tried

```
String bobo = thetext.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
intent.setPackage("com.samsung,android.app.galaxyfinder");
intent.putExtra("query", bobo);
startActivity(intent);
```

to no avail. I tried just ACTION_VIEW in there too to no avail. Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

If I have misunderstood you I apologise but maybe this could help you.

[Search Intent|Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/components/intents-common.html#Search)

Comment: Fact: You comment is not helpful especially the opinion part.  My question is about the specific intent needed for a specific application and has little to do with your link posted. I highly recommend you not posting unhelpful comments that waste people's time.

Comment: This does what is asked. You want to search s finder it does the same thing. Otherwise please do explain the question. Do you wish to search within an app or send a query to search the whole phone.